# Call Function From One Function To Another In A Class PHP

Tags: php, oop

I would like to use a function from inside my class in another function. I have tried just calling it but it does not seem to work. Here is what I am doing:

```
class dog {
    public function info($param) {
        //Do stuff here
    }
    public function call($param2) {
        //Call the info function here
        info($param2);
        //That does not seem to work though, it says info is undefined.
    }
}
```

So basically my question is how do I call a function from another in a class. Thank You, I am VERY new to classes! :D

Comment: `$this->info($param2);` and done! [`Basic OOP PHP`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)

Comment: Oh Thank You!!! I will read the link you have posted :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to call method: undefined function error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149234/trying-to-call-method-undefined-function-error)

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you always need to use `$this->` to call a class method (or any attribute). In your case the code is:

```
public function call($param2) {
        //Call the info function here
        $this->info($param2);
        //That does not seem to work though, it says info is undefined.
}
```

Please note that If you declare your method as static, then you will have to use either `self::` or `static::`.

This is a basic PHP OOP syntax, for more information [read the doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)